# Django's CKEditor not appearing in Admin Panel

Tags: python, django

I have a simple Django application that allows me to create an article. It contains a title, date, author (auto applied) and body. Using the RichTextField, I created my body in the models, however, a simple plain text area is appearing in my admin instead of my RichTextField, see
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH9mS.png)

Something I found during an HTML inspection is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9myL.png). I didn't add that and I have no idea how to fix that as well.

Here is all the relevant code

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import Article
admin.site.site_header = 'Neostorm Admin'
@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js',)
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    #Order the articles model by the date of update
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
```

Relevant settings.py configurations

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = "images/"
CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'articles/'
CKEDITORBackGround = '#7D001D'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        "width": "100%",
        'skin': 'moono-lisa',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
        'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll']},
            {'name': 'forms',
             'items': ['Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',
                       'HiddenField']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl',
                       'Language']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
            {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks']},
            '/',  # put this to force next toolbar on new line
            {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
                # put the name of your editor.ui.addButton here
                'Preview',
                'Maximize',

            ]},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
        # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
        # 'height': 291,
        # 'width': '100%',
        # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
        # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
        # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
        # 'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
            # your extra plugins here
            'div',
            'autolink',
            'autoembed',
            'embedsemantic',
            'autogrow',
            'widget',
            'lineutils',
            'clipboard',
            'dialog',
            'dialogui',
            'elementspath'
        ]),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't my configuration, it was the actual library. I installed tiny mce (which I recommend) and it fixed the problem instantly.

I recommend these resources if you want to use tiny mce

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9VZlqCbiLk
- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/django/
- https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Some of the static files have different names than what is referenced in the docs, so please keep that in mind when it comes to configuration within your settings.py.